# Bitxor function of positive and negative values in matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I am performing bitxor between two arrays. This is my java code

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int SYMBOL_SIZE=3;
        byte[][] D = new byte[2][SYMBOL_SIZE];
        D[0][0]=57;
        D[0][1]=22;
        D[0][2]=82;

        D[1][0]=23;
        D[1][1]=0;
        D[1][2]=-60;
        for (int j=0; j<SYMBOL_SIZE; j++)
            {
            //System.out.print((byte) (D[1][j]));
            D[1][j]=(byte) (D[1][j] ^ D[0][j]);
            System.out.print(D[1][j]);
            System.out.println();
            }

     }
}
```

The result return

```
46                                                                                          
22                                                                                          
-106
```

Now, I want to perform that above function in MATLAB. I checked that `^`operation in JAVA similar the bitxor in matlab. Is it right? However, when I run it the matlab, it has error. This is my matlab code

```
SYMBOL_SIZE=3;
D=zeros(2,SYMBOL_SIZE);
D(1,1:SYMBOL_SIZE)=[57,22,82];
D(2,1:SYMBOL_SIZE)=[23,0,-60];
%% Perform ^ operation
Result=bitxor(D(1,1:SYMBOL_SIZE),D(2,1:SYMBOL_SIZE));
```

The result is

```
Error using bitxor
Inputs must be non-negative integers.
```

How to achieve the result look like JAVA code by MATLAB language? Thank in advance

Comment: Try 196 instead of -60. You'll get 150 but that's the same bit pattern as -106.

Comment: Yes, But I must check the sign of each value before implement bitxor, right? After that, I must convert it again . For example, the result of 196 bitxor with 82 is 150. After that, the finnal result is 150-256=-106. Is it inconvenience?

Comment: I don't know from where you get -60 in the first place, and why. Typically, bit ops use non-negative values, or literals written in hex. You should have used 196 in the Java code, with a short or an int.

Comment: @laune: I get it when I read a file. It returns negative value

Comment: There really is -60 etc in that file? Using signed values for byte values that (as it seems) do not represent numbers but bit patterns is weird. How about converting them to a positive short or int and proceeding with that? (Why the parallel effort Java/MATLAB?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation of [`bitxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html#input_argument_integ1), "if [both arguments] are double arrays, and `assumedtype` is not specified, then MATLAB treats integ1 and integ2 as **unsigned 64-bit integers**."

So you just need to supply an `assumedtype` that can take on negative values (i.e., any `int` type without a leading `u`) like

```
Result=bitxor(D(1,1:SYMBOL_SIZE),D(2,1:SYMBOL_SIZE),'int64');
```

---

On versions of MATLAB before R2012b ([R2012a `bitxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/techdoc/ref/bitxor.html?searchHighlight=bitxor)), you may need to explicitly cast the inputs and they must be unsigned.
In order to use signed numbers, you'll need to do some type casting to get the exact:

```
a = int64(D(1,1:SYMBOL_SIZE));
b = int64(D(2,1:SYMBOL_SIZE));
a = typecast(a,'uint64');
b = typecast(b,'uint64');
Result = typecast(bitxor(a,b),'int64');
```

But note that now `Result` will be of type `int64` (or whatever you cast with), and the conversion back to double will need to be done explicitly as well if needed:

```
Result=double(Result);
```

Likely, the `assumedtype` option was added to make this type conversion stuff less cumbersome.

Comment: I am using matlab 2012.

Comment: Thank TroyHaskin, But it still error Undefined function 'bitxor' for input arguments of type 'int64'.

Comment: @user8430 And that appears to be because prior to R2012b, signed integers were not supported.  I'm not sure how to remedy this.

Comment: @user8430 I think I figured out a way.  See the updated-updated answer.